# Parameter is not valid while retrieving image from image data type DB

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio-2010

This is my code; I try to retrieve image. I try to resolve but fail:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select pic from pic where idimg= '" + listBox1.Text + "'", con);
SqlDataReader r;

con.Open();
r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (r.Read())
{
    byte[] storedImage = (byte[])(r["pic"]);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(storedImage);
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms); // Error :Parameter is not valid
}

r.Close();
con.Close();
```

Comment: So....what's the full error message?  Is there an exception?  If so, post the full stack trace here.  What is the structure of the database table?

Comment: `select pic` is a column in your database? Or you mean `select * ` (everything)?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

parameter is not valid is only show.while image save on db without given perimeter and no error is generate the error is occurring while retrieve from DB